# error 7#7: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx, docker, php-7, fpm

I have just compiled php7 in a docker container, and try to serve it with ngnix (which is also in a docker container).

and using php-fpm ...

I just serve a simple php file *index.php* with a simple line: `echo "Hello World";` for a test. In the log of `docker-compose up`, for the ngnix server I have the error message:

> error 7#7: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's highly likely that it's an issue with the nginx configuration. Does it have enough memory allocated?

Comment: no problems with nginx, since i can serve static files, only with php files, on which i have a 502, maybe lies in the use of runit to start php-fpm , in docker container ??

Comment: where do you allocate memory in nginx ?

Comment: Solved : i had un uncommented line in php-fpm conf : listen.allowed_clients = , which was probably accepting no connection.